# Changing Font Weights and Making Lines Thinner in pdfbox

Tags: scala, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I have a pdf written with pdfbox and I would like to change the font such that it has less weight (setFontWeight() seemed like a natural choice):

```
val fontD: PDFontDescriptorDictionary  = new PDFontDescriptorDictionary();
    fontD.setFontWeight(100)
    fontD.setFontName("PDType1Font.HELVETICA")
    val customFont: PDSimpleFont = new PDTrueTypeFont()
    font1.setBaseFont("Helvetica")
    font1.setFontDescriptor(fontD)
```

This doesn't change the font weight however.  Do I have any alternatives to this?  What about reducing line weights with "drawLine" in pdfbox?

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a few curious things in this code. Type1 fonts haven't been made for a very long time now (opentype won. Adobe's contribution there is the type2 CFF. They even converted their entire type1 catalog to type2 opentype way back when) and unless you're loading a font collection, individual fonts only encode single weights, so I would expect setting the weight to do nothing: you'd have to load the dedicated font for the weight you need.

Comment: Ah, so if I need to have a Helvetica-style font of a desired weight, my only option is to find a font of the given weight that looks closest to Helvetica?

Comment: setFontWeight() just changes the descriptor, not the font. What you did was like changing the cup size on a bra label and expecting the contents to change too. Yes, you'd just need to find another font.